# How to use UNET properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried using UNET for a game of mine.

I added spawn points got my player prefab
and Network Manager HUD, Network Manager

[Network Components Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlYP.jpg)

[Spawn Points Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA2Ey.jpg)

Now there's a host and clients after the host.

[Hosts and Clients Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGb5i.jpg)

Now I want to make a method which is getting called when a someone is connecting.
What do I type? And where do I do it? (in what script if there's no script taking care of the network)

If you have suggestions for code makeover like "listen 9000" I'm fine as long as it will make it work I just need to understand how does it work.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are several callbacks to achieve that, like "NetworkManager.OnClientConnect": https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.OnClientConnect.html

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the NetworkManager class and implement the virtual functions you need. See [NetworkManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html)

You then add your custom NetworkManager class to a gameobject instead of the original NetworkManager.

Another way is to have the NetworkManager auto spawn players and add scripts to the player objects that triggers the needed functionality. These scripts should extend the NetworkBehaviour class instead of MonoBehaviour. See OnStartServer and OnStartClient on [NetworkBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour.html)

Comment: Yes I'd like to have an example I'm not sure how to add the class to the gameobject ..